# Cannot set up constructor correctly

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Here is my task at hand: (using netbeans)

a.Does not inherit from any other class

b.Contains four private instance, all of type “Point” ,variables called

```
point1
point2
point3
point4
```

c.
Create a constructor that takes the following values:

i. `double x1, double y1,double x2, double y2,double x3, double y3, double x4,double y4`

ii. The constructor should create and set the four Point instance variables

d.The class should contain the following getters:

i. `getPoint1( )`
ii. `getPoint2( )`
iii. `getPoint3( )`
iv. `getPoint4( )`

e.The class should contain a method called `getCoordinatesAsString()` that returns the formatted S`tring "%s, %s, %s, %s\n", point1, point2, point3, point4`

Here is what i have so far:

```
public class Quadrilateral {

private Point point1;
private Point point2;
private Point point3;
private Point point4;

public Quadrilateral(double x1, double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3,double x4,double y4)
{
    point1 = x1,y1;
    point2 = x2,y2;
    point3 = x3,y3;
    point4 = x4,y4;
}

public Point getPoint1()
{
    return point1;
}

public Point getPoint2()
{
    return point2;
}
public Point getPoint3()
{
    return point3;
}
public Point getPoint4()
{
    return point4;
}

    public String getCoordinatesAsString()
{
    return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", point1,point2,point3,point4);
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%s:\n%s", "Coordinates of Quadrilateral are", getCoordinatesAsString());
}



}
```

I cannot figure out how to set up the constructor correctly. I get an error saying incompatible types, double cannot be converted to Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not constructing the Points properly.

Try :

```
public Quadrilateral(double x1, double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3,double x4,double y4)
{
    point1 = new Point(x1,y1);
    point2 = new Point(x2,y2);
    point3 = new Point(x3,y3);
    point4 = new Point(x4,y4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of a class (an object), you invoke its constructor.
This is done by using the `new` keyword.

The `Point` structure is a class, and you wish to create an instance of it.
You are instead trying to asign it to a `double` value, while you should create a new `Point` object and pass the two double values in as `parameters` in to the Point `constructor`.

So create the points in the `Quadrilateral` constructor the same way you create the `Quadrilateral` object, by using the `new` keyword!

Comment: makes much more sense when you explain it that way

Comment: Glad to hear, feel free to mark answer as correct and/or upvote, if you feel it gave you the answer you needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You also may send point to the `Quadrilateral` constructor. Make an overloaded version of the `Quadrilateral` constructor -

```
public Quadrilateral(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3, Point point4)
{
    this.point1 = point1;
    this.point2 = point2;
    this.point3 = point3;
    this.point4 = point4;
}
```

Then from the client of `Quadrilateral` you may construct a `Quadrilateral` like this way-

```
Quadrilateral aQuadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2),new Point(x3, y3), new Point(x4, y4) );
```

Comment: That is a good idea, unfortunately in my instructions i have to use Public Quadrilateral(double x1, double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3,double x4,double y4)

Comment: Then you may use either of solution given here.

Comment: Or you may use the last line of my post

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of your **Quadrilateral** class to

```
point1 = new Point(x1,y1);
point2 = new Point(x2,y2);
point3 = new Point(x3,y3);
point4 = new Point(x4,y4);
```

And your **Point** class should look something like

```
Class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point (double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getCoordiantes () {
        return String.format("("+ %f +","+ %f +")" , this.x, this.y);
    }

    (...) //other methods
}
```